# transform: translate() and matrix3d() break hover and click in Microsoft Edge

Tags: css, hover, transform, translate, microsoft-edge

A situation arises with block elements that use `transform: translate()` and `matrix3d()` as part of an animation sequence (animation is by GSAP, but that shouldn't be relevant to the problem since all GSAP does is update CSS properties in real-time).

Expected: Regardless of size or position, elements should remain interactive to mouse. (works properly in Chrome, FF, Safari, IE11).

Actual: Some will work, once or twice, if you're lucky, and then after that none of the others will respond to the mouse (bad behaviour in MS Edge).

Here is a working use case of this issue: idx.klick.com
(click past the welcome screen and try playing with the floating balls)

Has anyone encountered this or found a solution?

Comment: Can you post some of your relevant code and tell us what you've attempted that's breaking, specifically?

Comment: Hi Aaron, the issue is visible on the site listed in the question. The symptom seems to be that as soon as we perform css translate with transform() and matrix3d() that includes a negative 'Z' coordinate, the element becomes unclickable and unhoverable in EDGE. Attempts to "inspect" the affected element causes its parent container to be selected (as if there is a z-index issue, and yet we have ruled out z-index completely as the cause).

Comment: Our working theory is that EDGE is blocking clicks or hovers on any element whose translateZ is "beneath" the neutral '0' background stage. But negative values for Z in 3d css transforms are a perfectly legal part of the standard, and this works correctly in all other browsers including IE11.

Comment: Hey Christin, this question needs the working code to be added to the question itself; external links to demos are not acceptable on their own. PS, no need to write Edge in all caps. It's just Edge, MS Edge, or Microsoft Edge :-)

Comment: There's at least one negative z-index-related bug filed on Microsoft Edge, so I wouldn't necessarily rule that out just yet.

Comment: The code for this menu system is just way too huge and complex to post here.